# Querying a nested array in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have the following data index in Elasticsearch with the following syntax:

```
PUT /try1
{
"mappings" : {
  "product" : {
   "properties" : {
     "name": { "type" : "text" },
     "categories": {
       "type": "nested",
       "properties": {
         "range":{"type":"text"}
       }
     }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

The range type has an array of words:["high","medium","low"]
I need to access the range element inside the nested category. I tried using the following syntax:

```
GET /try1/product/_search
{
    "query": {
        "nested" : {
            "path" : "categories",
            "query" : {
                "bool" : {
                    "must" : [
                    { "match" : {"categories.range": "low"} }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

However, I am getting an error with the message:
 "reason": """failed to create query:...

Can someone please offer a solution to this?

Comment: How do you run your query? Using a programming language or ... ? Your query seems to be correct. I suggest you to run the query using `chrome sense extension` and provide the full error.

Answer (score 0):

@KGB can you try to make your query slightly differently like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "categories.range": "low"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested" : {
            "path" : "categories",
            "query" : {
                "bool" : {
                    "must" : [
                    { categories.range": "low"}
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This worked perfectly